# Why do we say only "Morid Hatal" without words "Mashiv haru'ach" before it?

Tags: passover, shemoneh-esrei, geshem-tal-ruach, summer

During winter months, we say "You make the wind blow and the rain fall". During the summer, we say only "You make the dew fall." Why don't we include the beginning part about blowing the wind? I noticed that during *Tefillat Tal* on the 1st day of Pesach, we say the full phrase *Mashiv Haru'ach umorid hatal*. Why is that the only exception?

Comment: Actually there is a Machlokes regarding this. There are some Chasidim [(Munkatch, Zidichoiv and others)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10143&st=&pgnum=5&hilite=) that do say Mashiv HaRuach Umorid Hatal during the summer months.

Comment: Who's "we"? [15]

Comment: I say the full version.

Comment: If I recall, the Be'er Heitev says to say the entire thing.

Comment: I must say that in some variants of Nusach Ashkenaz, "morid hatal" is not there; instead "mashiv haruach umorid hageshem" is just added for the winter months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Aruch Hashulchan OC 114:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=198) writes that "generally speaking wind brings clouds from which rain falls and therefore we mention them together". Being that wind is not directly associated with the gathering of dew it is not mentioned together. However, Shulchan Aruch OC 114 does state that if one mentions "mashiv haruach" in the summer he does not have to repeat the prayer.

The mention of ruach in Teffilas Tal seems to be in order to fill the meter of the poem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [scientific answer](http://www.wral.com/weather/blogpost/3695552/), actually:

> a windy night will often end up free of dew, because the resulting
>   mixing of the lower atmosphere prevents the surfaces from cooling
>   sufficiently by constantly transporting a fresh supply of warmer air
>   to the surface from a few hundred feet up.

Fog is an "enhanced" form of dew. One can easily simulate the experiment by taking a hot shower such that it fogs up the bathroom. If you turn on a fan, the fog almost immediately dissipates.

Thus, generally, wind and dew are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Because dew doesn't require wind, whereas rainstorms, especially in Israel, do. (Dew forms from condensation, but rain requires clouds which need to get blown by the wind.)

I don't know why there is an exception for the first time. Maybe as a transition.

*No sources, sorry.*