# Said "משיב הרוח": continue "ומוריד הטל"?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chutz-laaretz, nusach-ashkenaz, geshem-tal-ruach

Some, during the summer, say in the *amida* (*sh'mone esre*)

> ‏… מחיה מתים אתה רב להושיע מכלכל חיים בחסד…‏‎  (1)

with nothing between "להושיע" and "מכלכל". Some others say

> ‏… מחיה מתים אתה רב להושיע **משיב הרוח ומוריד הטל** מכלכל חיים בחסד…‏‎  (2),

and at least one other version exists also. During the winter, we say

> ‏… מחיה מתים אתה רב להושיע **משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם** מכלכל חיים בחסד…‏‎  (3).

---

Suppose someone uses version (1) but, in error, starts to say version (3). He gets as far as having said "משיב הרוח" and realizes his mistake. Should he

- continue "ומוריד הטל מכלכל חיים בחסד" as in version (2), as, that way, what he's saying is correct according to some version;
- continue "מכלכל חיים בחסד" as if he hadn't added "משיב הרוח", as adding two words is bad enough and he ought not compound his error by adding two more; or
- something else?

Comment: can personally vouch for version (2). i say it -- that is what they say in the local shteibel. see also here: http://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_01_17_12/

Comment: What's wrong with saying משיב הרוח in the summer? There's wind in the summer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* 19:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%98#.28.D7.92.29) says to omit "ומוריד הטל" and continue "מכלכל חיים בחסד". This is despite his acknowledging in 19:3 the existence of the version "משיב הרוח ומוריד הטל".

Answer (score -3):

Version 2 is incorrect. It is scientifically impossible for dew to fall if there is too much wind. There is also a previous Mi Yodeya discussion on this question see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37586/why-do-we-say-only-morid-hatal-without-words-mashiv-haruach-before-it).

Comment: Version 2 is quoted by the [Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 18 (3)](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=19)!